# sum dynamic values through each function

Tags: jquery

I want to calculate sum of textfield(which can be 3 or 2 etc) values.

Here is the code I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[id^="revenue-"]').on('input', function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var bpid = id.replace("revenue", "basepoint");
        var bpvalue = 0;
        $('#' + bpid).each(function() {
            var bp_id = $(this).attr("id");
            console.log("begin: " + bpvalue); * * // it gives me undefined on console**
            var bpvalue = bpvalue + Number($('#' + bp_id).val());
            $('#totalbasepoint').val((bpvalue).toFixed(2)); * * // thus here value is NaN**
        });

    });
});
```

Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: are the textboxes coming dynamically??

Comment: no text box are static and iam getting values in Number($('#'+bp_id).val());. But the problem is with the bpvalue =0; it gives me undefined

Comment: could you show you html code??

Comment: Post some `html` too..

Comment: Instead of `var bpvalue = bpvalue + Number($('#' + bp_id).val());`, use `bpvalue = bpvalue + Number($('#' + bp_id).val());`, remove the `var` from there.

Comment: You are using this `$('[id^="revenue-"]')` which means you id is starting with `revenue-` and when you are replacing the id you are using this `var bpid = id.replace("revenue", "basepoint");` which means the id is `revenue`...its wrong because of which your each function is not calling

Comment: each function is calling as iam getting values for all the three input box under each. The problem is with the var bpvalue=0; which is getting as undefined and thus result is NaN